# Consumer delay with producer-consumer pattern

Tags: queue, producer-consumer, python-multithreading

Problem:

1. query1, query2, query3 are added to queue. Consumer starts consuming the added query's right away. Everything works fine.
2. After queue is empty, same query's are added to queue again. For some reason consumer now hangs for some time (5-10 seconds) before it starts consuming the given query's.

Pseudo:

```
from Queue import queue
from Threading import thread

fifo = queue()

class Producer:

    def produce_query(self, query):
         global fifo
         fifo.put(query)
         if consumer.not_started():
             consumer.start()

class Consumer(Thread):

    def run(self):
         global fifo
         while True:
              query = fifo.get(block=True)
              self.execute(query)
```

I'm not sure if I have misunderstood something with the queue work principle. Do I need to notify the queue/consumer to make the consumer working right away somehow or what?

I'd appreciate the help!

Comment: Is your consumer thread yielding the CPU when the queue is empty so that the producer can make progress?  Does it stop blocking the FIFO?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean with the consumer yielding the CPU. How do I make sure it doesn't? The blocking of fifo is stopped after some delay.

Comment: There’s a function in every threading library, usually with a name like yield(), that causes a thread, when it has nothing useful to do but wait, to yield the CPU so that other threads can work faster.  A consumer with nothing to consume falls into this category.  A consumer also shouldn’t block if it’s not doing anything; don’t hold onto locks longer than needed for an atomic update.